# htaccess causing image to not render in browser

Tags: php, .htaccess, webserver, laravel-5.4

I just uploaded my laravel project in my host and requested the host company to upgrade my php version to 5.6. They did and as I check on the htaccess file I see that there is this line of code

```
ForceType application/x-httpd-php56
```

I don't know what this is so I experimented.
I created a phpinfo file and commented that ForceType code; viewed phpinfo in browser and saw that php version was reverted to 5.5.

I again uncommented the ForceType code and check phpinfo to see that php version is 5.6.
So ok, the php version has been resolved. I big problem that arises from this ForceType in htaccess is that the images on my project are not being rendered on the browser.

```
The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors
```

Weird this is, with ForceType commented from htaccess all images are rendered correctly in the browser.

Has any of you encountered this? and if yes how did you solved the issue?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: So *every* request is being forced to be a PHP request, including requests for images? That should probably be more selective and only apply to .php files and/or specific folders.

Comment: I don't really know, That code there is put by the host company to maybe force the use of php version 5.6. I tried removing it and php version reverted back to 5.5